# What is equivalent to TestCase.client in normal script

Tags: python, django

For example with `TestCase`
I can check `login` `post` and so on with `self.client`

```
class TestMyProj(TestCase):
   response = self.client.login(username="user@example.com", password="qwpo1209")

   response = self.client.post('/cms/content/up',
        {'name': 'test', '_content_file': fp},
        follow=True)
```

However now I want to use this in script not in test case.

because this is very useful to make initial database.

I want to do like this.

```
def run():
   response = client.login(username="user@example.com", password="qwpo1209")    
   with open('_material/content.xlsx','rb') as fp:
       response = client.post('/cms/content/up',
       {'name': 'faq_test', 'scenario_content_file': fp})
```

What is equivalent to `TestCase.client` in normal script??

---

**More details**

If there is not file upload, I can make database directory from model.

However, I want to upload file and parse then put into database, same as user does. (via `form_valid` and so on)

so, I want to use `post` for url from script.

---

**My Solution**

Use  `from django.test.client import Client` as Willem Van Onsem mensioned.

somehow `client.login` returns `True` not `response`.

So, I use `post` to login

```
def run():
    client = Client()
    #response = client.login(username="guest@guest.com", password="guest")# it doesn't work some how.
    response = client.post('/login/', {'username': 'guest@guest.com', 'password': 'guest'},follow=True)
    with open('_material/content.xlsx','rb') as fp:
        response = client.post('/cms/content/up',
        {'name': 'test','is_all':"True", '_content_file': fp})
```

Comment: This sounds like [a XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to do `client.login()` and `client.post()` in a "normal script"? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? There are almost certainly better solutions to your original problem which we can suggest if you give more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice is very helpful to progress. I added comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [**`Client`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client), so:

```
from django.test.client import Client

def run():
    client = Client()
    response = client.login(username="user@example.com", password="qwpo1209")
    response = client.post(
        '/cms/content/up',
        {'name': 'test', '_content_file': fp},
        follow=True
    )
```

The documentation discusses the parameters that can be passed when constructing a `Client` object.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried with this and there comes no error. but after script finished, there is no entry in database. maybe because it is test ?

Comment: Solved. I use `response = client.post('/login/', {'username': 'user@example.com', 'password': 'qwpo1209'},follow=True)`  it works. and database entry is not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I recommend to create command to make initial database instead of  using the Client class that we can use to test the application.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/
You can also take advantage of bulk methods to create many instances in a single query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. but I want to use `form post` Because it is including file uploading. if file uploading is not included, I can directly make db data..

Comment: @whitebear I suggest using a library such as `requests` then. This is a generic HTTP library that isn't specific to Django, so it is useful no matter what language the server is written in. A script that uses requests can be run anywhere that has access to the server over the network. Where as a script using `Client` must be run on the same machine as the Django code is on.